# How to disable multiple classes using :not(selector)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to disable multiple options from the drop down list.
So I tried to use parentclass:not(subclass1, subclass2);
These sub class are the options in drop down list. 
Please can anyone suggest how to do it? I am using jquery in ember framework.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the **"disabled"** option directly.

The solution is to replace the select-option to **ul-li** kinda syntax and apply styling accordingly.

The other solution is not to use the disabled attribute at all and handle the action in JavaScript or jQuery by using a custom class.

Comment: Thank you mohanesh